# Firebase request not connecting

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-tools

I am using Firebase to run the backend for my app. When I execute `NODE_ENV=debug firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions` it just says

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub

Error: TIMEOUT: Port 4400 on 127.0.0.1 was not active within 60000ms
```

(The timeout thing is after 60000ms because it received no request)

And after the emulators start, I send a request to `http://localhost:5001` but it doesnt connect.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2379). The workaround is to specify your localhost address (ex. `127.0.0.1`) instead of `localhost` and add a host attribute inside your firebase.json with 127.0.0.1 also.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2379#issuecomment-972852609

Example:

```
"firestore": {
    "port": 8080,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
},
```